# Exporting from bcp command to csv is not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, bcp

I'm really struggling with this particular query, any help would be greatly appreciated,

```
create table test(int a, int b, int c)

INSERT INTO test
select 5, 6, 7
union all
select 1, 2, 3

DECLARE @sql varchar(2000),
@filename varchar(200)
SET @sql      = 'select * from test '
set @filename = 'D:\New folder\myfile.csv '

set @sql = 'bcp "' + @sql + '" queryout "' +  @filename +'" -c -r"''\n" -t"'',''" -S localhost\mytest -T'

EXEC Master..xp_CmdShell @SQL
```

I tried to export into csv file but my data doesnot start with ' values.

Currently I am getting

```
5','6','7'
1','2','3'
```

Instead I am expecting the csv file start with the ' everynew line in the starting position like

```
 '5','6','7'
 '1','2','3'
```

I used different quoted identifier but still it doesnot work.

Comment: Why do you need to export it in that format?  it doesn't make any sense to me.  Simply export it in its native format (`-n`, which should be default), and specify a simple field terminator, such as comma or semi colon, like this `-t","`.  When you do the import, it should just work.

Comment: @Greg I dont have any alternative. and It's the client requirement which i need to fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QUOTENAME function to specify the single quote, and set column delimiter to just a comma.  You'll have to build out your query though.

```
    DECLARE @sql varchar(2000),
    @filename varchar(200)
    SET @sql = 'select QUOTENAME(a, CHAR(39)), QUOTENAME(b, CHAR(39)), QUOTENAME(c, CHAR(39)) from test'
    set @filename = 'D:\New folder\myfile.csv '

    set @sql = 'bcp "' + @sql + '" queryout "' +  @filename +'" -c -r"''\n" -t"," -S localhost\mytest -T'
```